# Differences between dropping in the editor an AI agent, vs spawning it from a game object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am having some problems spawning AI. I made a prefab, which works just fine when you add it to the scene in the editor; but if I spawn the same exact prefab in the scene, at runtime; I get problems on the AI Agent.

In particular, on the ThirdPersonCharacter script attached to the AI Agent (I am using the standard AI prefab in Unity). The agent continue to perform the idle animation, and II get a failure on the "CheckGroundStatus()" function; in particular the line

```
m_animator.applyRootMotion=false;
```

Which result in the GameObject to slide toward the destination, instead than transition to the walk animation state in the animator. I get that it is due the fact that the GO can't get grounded, but I do not understand what is different between the same exact prefab, spawned and add via editor.

Pretty sure that the problem must be something very simple, but I can't really get the issue here.

Comment: Sounds weird to mark my own answer, but I agree

Comment: I think they have a sort of "lock" for your own answer, that last for a day or 2. Last time that I did try to accept the answer, I did get a message saying that I have to wait. Plus it is always good to wait a bit before mark an answer, since someone else may have a better solution than mine, so it is good to have this wait period for your own answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this was nasty.

So the issue is simple: in the ThirdPersonCharacter script, you can see that there is code in the start function. This function happens at later time; so it may be possible that the prefab is not completely instntiated when it run, and that may cause issues like mine.

To solve it, simply change the Start() function with Awake() function. This will force the collider and components to initialize first, then the origin and check distance functions will run at first; giving the prefab the correct initialization to then be able to operate correctly.

Hope this will help others; I was stuck for few hours on this, before being able to see the issue.